# C++ array of pointer memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

In my class I have a dynamically allocated array of pointers. My declaration:

```
 array = new Elem* [size];
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = NULL;
 }
```

So there is an array of pointers, where each pointer points to a simple Elem struct.

The main question is, how should I properly deallocate the array. If I use only:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   delete array[i];
}
```

Valgrind reports 1 not-freed block, which is traced to the line where 'array = new Elem* [size];' states.

On the other hand if I add to the previous code:

```
delete array;
```

Which I thought is correct, valgrind reports 0 not-freed blocks, which is perfect, BUT it reports

```
Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
```

exactly on the line where 'delete array;' is. I tried 'delete []array' too, but that's just "1 not-freed blocks" too then! If somebody could explain me the proper way it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

is working probably fine. It is working in one of my classes (I have two similar) the other still reports some small leak. I would think it's just a minor bug somewhere, but valgrind still points to the line where

```
array = new Elem* [size];
```

stands.

**EDIT2:**
I solved this as well, thank you for your exhausting contribution!!

Comment: Where does it say that not freed block got allocateD?

Comment: Make your life easier: delete all of the above, and use Boost [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but is there some reason you can't use a std::vector<Elem> to greatly simplify the memory management?

Comment: Indeed there is, it's a school work and we are not allowed to use that, probably the point is to learn how to do this properly.

Comment: @aGr:  Would "homework" tag be appropriate in this case?  It might keep others from pushing the vector angle as well.  :)

Comment: Alright, will do :). See the edit @BillyONeal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should free everything in the array (if dynamically allocated) and then free the array itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // only free inside if dynamically allocated - not if just storing pointers
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array; // necesarry
```

Comment: You mean he should delete all the objects the pointers in the array point to, then use `delete[]` which deletes the objects in the array (which are pointers) and the array itself.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it's not accurate to say that the objects in the array are deleted, rather they are destroyed. Pointers don't have destructors, so nothing happens in that step.

Comment: @MarkRansom Pointers have destructors. C++ has them so templates work with builtin types.

Comment: The semantics of `delete[]` are that it deletes the objects in the array. In this case, that doesn't do much -- but the point is that it's a mistake to say that `delete[]` doesn't "free everything in the array". The OP's issue is that he has an array of pointers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Mark is correct. Each element is destroyed (which is a no-op for raw pointers, due to the trivial destructor), then the entire block is freed at once.  Each element is NOT individually freed.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, the inside of the array is truly dyn. allocated.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Only because the objects are pointers and there is nothing to free. My point is that the semantics of `delete[]` are that it *does* free the individual elements of the array (to the extent that is necessary). That just happens to be a non-operation with pointers because their destructor has nothing to free. `delete[]` *does* free "everything in the array" -- but all that's in the array are pointers. This is an array of pointers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No it doesn't free individual elements.  It calls the destructor, if any, for each individual element (in reverse order of construction) and then frees the memory block used by the whole array (both content and metadata).  There's no individual freeing of each element.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're both right. The entire block becomes free, which also makes the individual elements free. Stop being pedants.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Calling `free` on a memory block that contains multiple objects frees all of those objects. The internal details of how `delete` works are not the concern here -- its logical semantics are. That you can deallocate multiple objects with one call to `free` (if `delete[]` even does that internally which it may or may not) is purely an implementation detail. No program could ever tell the difference. (And nothing prohibits an implementation from using separate freeing operations for each object in an array if it wants to. No rule requires delete to even call free.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: We're not talking about the function `free` from malloc.h, we're talking about the action of deallocating (or freeing) memory.  But in fact, the standard requires the implementation to invoke the deallocation function `operator delete[]`, and it must call it once, for the entire array.  And it must do so after calling the destructor for each element, if one exists, in reverse order of construction.  An implementation using separate deallocation (freeing) operations would be non-comformant.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It must call `operator delete[]` once to free the memory for the entire array which is precisely the same as freeing the memory allocated to each object. Whether it does this with one call to the underlying allocation function or many is up to the implementation. The only conformance requirement is that the allocator place them all contiguously in the first place. There is no conformance requirement on the deallocation. You are conflating how it is typically done with the logical meaning of what's done. Logically, all elements are freed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Can't say anything about the internal operation of `operator delete[](void*)`, because the user can replace it.  I'm strictly talking about the code the compiler produces for the `delete[]` operator, which must call element destructors, if they exist, in reverse order of construction, and then make one call to the `operator delete[](void*)` function.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Right, but the `operator delete[]` function can do whatever it wants. The logical affect will be that the memory occupied by each individual object is freed. (And that's why this follows up calling all the destructors -- that is necessary to achieve this logical affect of freeing the memory occupied by each object, whether directly or indirectly.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, *it's a mistake to say that delete[] doesn't "free everything in the array"* - since the destructor for the pointers in the array does not "free" the object pointed to by the pointers, this statement is incorrect. We're probably agreeing that Pubby8's solution is the correct one but just disagreeing on terminology.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The objects pointed to by those pointers aren't in the array. The array is an array of pointers. The code was `array = new Elem* [size];`. Note the '*' after 'Elem' and the []'s after that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yup pretty sure we're just disagreeing on terminology. In the context of the original question, it's important to note that just deleting the array allocated with `new` is not sufficient to clean up memory. Contrast against using `std::shared_ptr<Elem>` instead of `Elem*`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The only way we know it's not sufficient is because the OP said so. If, for example, the objects that the pointers point to are owned by something else (that will clean them up), all that needs to be deleted is the array itself. It happens that in this case, he also no longer needs the objects those pointers point to -- at least, we are assuming he does. It's possible he still needs some of them and telling him to delete them all will make his code crash. That's why I think it's more important to make sure the OP understands what does what rather than just giving him some code.

Answer (score 8):

You need:

```
delete [] array;
```

Because it's an array.

I just noticed your note that you tried this too - it's the proper thing to do so I don't know why you'd still be getting an error.

**Edit:** This deserves a more thorough explanation.

When you create a pointer using `new`, the pointer may be to a single element or an array of elements depending on the syntax you use. But the pointer type is the same in both cases! The compiler relies on you to know what the pointer points to and treat it accordingly.

```
Elem ** single = new Elem*;    // pointer to one pointer
single[0] = new Elem;          // OK
single[1] = new Elem;          // runtime error, but not compile time

Elem ** array = new Elem* [2]; // pointer to array of pointers
array[0] = new Elem;           // OK
array[1] = new Elem;           // OK
```

When you delete a pointer, the destructor is called for the object it points to or for each element of the array. But since the pointer type is the same in each case, the compiler relies on you to give it the proper syntax so it knows what to do.

```
delete single;
delete [] array;
```

In your case the elements of the array are pointers also, and pointers don't have destructors. That means those pointers won't be deleted and will become memory leaks if you don't delete them first. You were correct to have a loop to delete them individually before the final delete.

Comment: The OP does need `delete []` but I wouldn't call it an array.

Comment: @cnicutar, if it's not an array then what would you call it? The `new []` syntax allocates an array.

Comment: @cnicutar, yes, a pointer to an array. I hope we're in agreement now.

Comment: It's an array (well, a pointer to one). Although it differs from the "array type"

Comment: @cnicutar, I must correct myself based on your comment - the pointer type is in fact a pointer to a single element, but the memory it points to is still an array. Somehow under the covers the memory subsystem tracks the difference.

Comment: @Pubby8 bingo. +1 to that :-)

Comment: A pointer is always a pointer to a single element whether it is a single object or the first element in an array. You need (element) delete vs. (array) delete[] to tell the compiler which it actually is. I would call it pointer to array.

Comment: This answer means I should use only delete[]? The pointers in the array (or whatever) are pointers to dynamically allocated Elems too, so I need to delete them too. (I should have mentioned that probably sorry). But the think is that the @Pubby8 solution works in one of my two classes. And I probably just have a minor leak somewhere else.

Comment: @aGr, I didn't include deleting each pointer in the array because I thought you already understood that part. Yes you still need it.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes thx I was just a bit confused due to so many comments here :)

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for deleting an array is like this:

```
delete[] array;
```

Your `for` loop to delete the objects pointed to by the elements of the array is fine. The deletion of the array itself is the only problem. You need **both** the `for` loop and then the `delete[]` to dispose of the array itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

I suspect that you have tried using the `for` loop, or the `delete[]`, but not both together. And if when you do that you still have leaks or errors, then you would need to show us the code that allocates the pointers that are elements of the array.

---

Using `std::vector<>` instead of an array would mean that you could stop worrying about these nitty gritty details and move to higher level of abstraction.

Comment: @David OK, I edited it. It's just amazing how the signal gets lots in all the noise.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need *both*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

You call `delete` exactly once for each time you called `new`.

Note that although you need to call `delete[] array` here (because you allocated it with `new[]`), the `delete[]` operator does *not* call the destructors on the objects pointed to by elements of the array. This is because the `delete[]` operator calls destructors on *objects* in the array, and your array contains pointers but not objects. Pointers do not themselves have destructors.

Comment: I think that formally, pointer types have trivial destructors, which do nothing.